# Rails 4: link_to image_tag with text - how to apply CSS to the text?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have the following code on my app:

```
<%= link_to (image_tag (attraction.image_url), id: "thumb_size2") + attraction.name, attraction_path(attraction) do %><%end%>
```

It results on a hyperlinked image formatted according to properties set in `#thumb_size2` CSS.

`attraction.name`, however, has no style attached to it and thus just "floats" around the page. Ideally, I'd like `#thumb_size2` CSS to also be applied to`attraction.name`.

I have searched previous questions posted with "link_to image_tag with text in rails" but none of the answers so far have worked (at least 6 of them)

Any suggestions how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

```
link_to (image_tag (attraction.image_url), id: "thumb_size2", :class => 'write css class name here') + attraction.name, attraction_path(attraction) do %><%end%>
```

you can add your class name in which you have defined the css

Comment: @ sprytechies it didn't work for me. The solution you provided seems to apply the class to the image instead. I'd like to `:class => 'write css class name here'` to be applied to `attraction.name`. Any other suggestions? I've also tried:`link_to (image_tag (attraction.image_url), id: "thumb_size2") + attraction.name, :class => 'write css class name here', attraction_path(attraction) do %><%end%>`

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure to remove the space between ( & link_to/ ( & image_tag. Also, include the id within image_tag as below: -

<%= link_to(image_tag(attraction.image_url, id: "thumb_size2"))

- I faced the problem and i just got it fixed.